# Adjusting axis properties in a time series graph

Tags: r, data-visualization

Consider the following code:

```
require(zoo)
data <- read.csv(file="summary.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE)
data = zoo(data$compressed, as.Date(data$date))
data <- aggregate(data, identity, tail, 1)
days = seq(start(data), end(data), "day")
data2 = na.locf(merge(data, zoo(,days)))

par(bty = 'n')
plot(data2,xlab='',ylab='entropy (bytes)')
```

How can one:

1. Adjust both the horizontal and vertical limits of the drawn axis to match the start and end of data (as an example, while the y value may vary between 20 and 1525, the axis shows 0 and 1500).
2. Increase the horizontal resolution (at least add some minor ticks) when the time series spans more years than are mentioned.

Using:

```
plot(data2,xlab='',ylab='entropy (bytes)', xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')
```

I get:

[image]

which is not exactly what I had in mind. The vertical scale doesn't start with the exact minimum (around 25), nor does it end with the exact maximum. The horizontal scale starts and ends in the middle. Hints?

Comment: Don't confuse the pretty label locations for the data. The figure region has been set to the range of the data. If you want axes with labels at specific, predefined points, turn off axis drawing in the `plot()` call with `axes = FALSE` and then draw the axes using `axis(side = 2)` for the y axis with suitable `at`, and the x-axis can be drawn using `axis.Date()` as per my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second Q, you can use `axis.Date()` with argument `labels = FALSE` to add minor tick marks at locations defined by argument `at`.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question try:

```
plot(data2,xlab='',ylab='entropy (bytes)', xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')
```